# Getting error ORA-00933 with execute immediate update

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to write a function which edits predefined characteristics of a task. I'm using `execute immediate` but I'm getting this error:

```
> Error report -
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "C##U1519.BEARBEITE", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 2
00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended"
```

This is my code

```
create or replace procedure bearbeite(Aufg_ID Aufgabe.Aufgaben_ID%TYPE, Eigenschaft VARCHAR2, Wert VARCHAR2)
as
  sql_query_string2 VARCHAR2(4000);
begin 
  --überprüfen 
  sql_query_string2 := 'UPDATE Aufgabe SET ' || Eigenschaft || ' = ' || Wert || ' where Aufgabe.Aufgaben_ID = ' || Aufg_ID;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query_string2;

exception
  when no_data_found then
      dbms_output.put_line('Kein Wert');
end;


-- test
set serveroutput on
begin
  bearbeite(1,'Ort','TH WILDAU');
end;
```

What should I do in order to make it work? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the error message? We can't guess it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should surround `varchar2` argument with single quotes ... which in pl/sql should be escaped and becomes ''

`sql_query_string2 := 'UPDATE Aufgabe SET ' || Eigenschaft || ' = ''' || Wert || ''' where Aufgabe.Aufgaben_ID = ' || Aufg_ID;`

Answer (score 4):

Dumping values into query strings is dangerous.  The most advertised danger is SQL injection, but that doesn't apply in many cases (where user input might have controls already in place).  A bigger issue is unexpected syntax errors.  More than one person -- I'm sure -- has encountered a name like `O'Neil` to their detriment when generating a query string.

I strongly recommend the use of parameters.  And this is easy in Oracle:

```
sql_query_string2 := 'UPDATE Aufgabe SET ' || Eigenschaft || ' = :1 where Aufgabe.Aufgaben_ID = :2';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query_string2 USING Wert, Aufg_ID;
```

This also means that you don't have to worry about whether or not to use single quotes.

The parameters can be named rather than numbered.

Sadly, you cannot use parameters for SQL identifiers -- table names, schema names, column names, functions, key words.  So, the column name does have to be incorporated into the string.